# Python Scrapy Framework Posting Wrong Images - Why/How Can I fix this?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working with the Scrapy framework for Python to scrape several entries including text and images from one site and post them to another, one by one. It all works well, except that the images are posting with the wrong corresponding text. I can't, for the life of me, figure out what to do differently.

Here is the code, if anyone could please help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it:

```
from flexmls.items import FlexmlsItem

class Epropertysites(BaseSpider):

name = 'epropertysites'

start_urls = ['http://www.epropertysites.com/']
URL  = 'http://www.epropertysites.com'

def parse(self, response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                     formdata={'i_login':settings.get('EPROP_USER', u''),
                                               'i_password':settings.get('EPROP_PASSW', u'')},
                                               callback=self.after_login)

def after_login(self, response):
    if 'is incorrect' in response.body:
        print 'Failed to login with\r\n press enter'
        self.log('Login failes', log.ERROR)
        raw_input()
        return
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(os.path.join("results", 'flexmls.csv'))):
        yield Request('http://www.epropertysites.com/myprop_add.htm',
                      meta={'item':row},
                      dont_filter=True,
                   callback=self.post_ad)

def post_ad(self, response):
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    try:
        print 'posting', item['address'].encode()
    except:pass
    formdata={'i_address':item['address'],
        'i_city':item['city'],
        'i_price':item['price'] if item['price'] else u'0',
        'i_state':item['state'].strip(),
        'i_zip':item['zip'].strip(),
        'i_county':item['county'],
       'i_mls':item['id'].strip(),
        'i_type':'1',
        'i_br':item['beds'] if item['beds'] else u'1',
        'i_ba':item['baths'] if item['baths'] else u'1',
        'i_sqft':item['sqft'],
        'i_year_blt':item['year_built'],
        'i_tagline':item['address'],
        'i_desc':item['description'].replace("\n", '\r\n'),
        'i_site_key':item['address'].replace(u" ", u'-').replace(u".", u'').strip(),
        'i_domain':'ePropertySites.com',
        'i_layout':'%.2d' %random.randint(2,5),
        'i_color02':'%.2d' %random.randint(1,12)
        }

    return FormRequest('http://www.epropertysites.com/myprop_add.htm?&f=3',
                       formdata=formdata,
                              meta={'item':item, 'form':formdata},
                       callback=self.post_images)


def encode_multipart_formdata(self, fields, files):

    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    for (filename, value) in files:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (filename, filename))
        L.append('Content-Type: image/jpeg')
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body

def post_images(self, response):
    if 'That Website Key is already being used' in response.body:return
    page = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    item = response.request.meta['item']
    images = eval(item['images'])
    fields = [('i_caption_1',''), ('v_max','1'),
              ('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mode"','send')]
    files = [ ( os.path.basename(image),
               open(os.path.join(settings.get("IMAGES_STORE"), image)).read())
             for image in images]
    content_type, body = self.encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
    return FormRequest(self.URL + page.select("//form/@action").extract()[0],
                           body=body,
                           method='POST',
                           headers={'Content-Type':content_type,
                                    'content-length':len(body)},
                           meta={"item":item, 'form':response.request.meta['form']},
                           callback=self.get_change_page)

def get_change_page(self, response):
    page = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    ad_id = page.select("//form/@action").re(r"&key=(\d+)&")[0].strip()
    return Request("http://www.epropertysites.com/myproperties.htm?&f=mod&key=%s" %ad_id,
                   meta={'item':response.request.meta['item'],
                         'form':response.request.meta['form'],
                         'id':ad_id},
                   callback=self.post_rest_info)
```

Comment: If you can give us a more concrete example of what you want, and what you are currently getting, that might help. As well as including a little more info about the workflow of the spider. But, as naive advice: make sure your xpaths are right! That was always my problem.